# How to add space between text and a button without using <br />

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I add space between text and button without using *<br />*?

I mean, make it not so adjacent between "How are you doing" from the first button. And make it not so adjacent between the second button and border.

```
<p>
      How are you doing?
      <br />
      <br />
      <button class='btn btn-default btn-xs pull-left'>
          Cancel
      </button>
      <button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right'>
          Confirm
      </button>
      <br />
  </p>
```

Comment: Just use padding in your css around the buttons.

Comment: @n_palum
What is bootstrap padding I can use?

Comment: You should be able to do it in css. You can add `padding: 5px;` to your classes that you want it for.

Comment: @ZimSystem
Where are you not understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spacing on web pages can be achieved primarily via the `margin` and `padding` CSS properties.

Put simply: padding affects spacing *inside* your element and margin affects spacing *outside* your element.

I'd recommend having a quick read of *[CSS Box Model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)* to get to grips with the subject.

*Padding* and *margin* can be set using all sorts of units. E.g., `px` `em` `rem` and even `%`.

You could set margin top in CSS like so:

```css
.my-css-class {
   margin-top: 50px;
}
```

You can apply CSS directly to elements like so:

```html
<p>
      How are you doing?
      <br />
      <br />
      <button style="margin-top: 2em" class='btn btn-default btn-xs pull-left'>
```

Although I wouldn't suggest making this a habit as it could potentially make maintaining your code significantly more difficult.